# Screen Capture for subsequent Computer Vision Processing

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, image-processing, opencv

What should I use to perform screen capture on Windows for subsequent image processing?

I seek to do follow-up image processing in OpenCV.

Comment: Does this need to be done in real time, or can you do the processing after the fact? Doing image processing on the screen catpure in real time is vastly more complex.  Also, do is this windows specific or do you need something that works cross platform?

Comment: I dont want to do it simultaneously - i just want to know how to capture the screen?? What are the apis - i am completely new to opencv - all these cv::Mat / cvcreateimage etc - are confusing me - and making me unsure of the thing i want to achieve. Processing does not need to be done simultaneously necessarily.

Comment: The term *Computer Vision* usually refers to the "real-world" image processing by the computer, not processing images from the computer's desktop.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

----
_[related reading](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the most straightforward thing to do is to use an off the shelf video capture tool to create an AVI file and then have image processing software operate on that, after the fact.

To get up and running:

- [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) is free and open source and has a simple gui.
- [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) is also FOSS and is more powerful, but less intuitive to use. Its primarily a video editing and processing tool, but it actually has sophisiticated capture capabilities.

Both work on Windows and both can output uncompressed AVI files that OpenCV can read.

If you are completely new to OpenCV, then I recommend a [O'Reilly's "Learning OpenCV"](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516130). Its for the older OpenCV 1.1 but it will at least get you started.

If you crack open that book, and you find that its way above your head, then I would consider trying to do your image processing in a higher level language. MATLAB with the Image Processing Toolbox is well suited for rapid prototyping of image processing and its a much more forgiving development environment. Its an interpretative language, so you can see-as-you-code.

Based on the question as stated, this is as much info as I can provide. Perhaps consider providing more details about your specific application requirements?